# Does the particle "を" (wo) have a special use when at the end of a sentence?

Tags: usage, particles, hiragana, particle-を, kana-usage

I thought the character "を" (wo) was only used for the particle whose only job was to indicate the direct object of a verb.

But today I saw it at the end of an exclamation on a sign I think on a shop:

> 西部に活力を!!

So what job is を doing here?

Comment: Very common: 素晴らしい一年を！

Comment: @Nicolas: A set phrase at the end of year is 良いお年を (よいおとしを), which can also be said as 良いお年をお迎えください (よいおとしをおむかえください) (I wish you a happy new year).

Comment: Two very common set phrases which end with particles: こんにちは and [こんばんは](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/131/which-is-correct-or)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's still the object marker. The sentence is just not finished and the verb is implied.

(there was a question mentioning suspended sentences but I cannot find it for the moment)

Anyway it's often used:

> フォースと共{とも}にあらんことを
>
> May the force be with you!

Additionally it gives some kind of propaganda feeling to the sentence.

Comment: Wow is there any part of a Japanese sentence you can't leave out? (-:

Comment: Generally speaking: No. :)

Comment: It's like Japanese color-by-numbers: the outline is there, but you have to pick your own verb to finish the picture.

Comment: Sentences ending with just を are very often interpreted in the meaning of wishing something to someone else, and I don't think anybody tries to fill in the verb for that, so perhaps you can say this specific を is quite stand-alone.

Comment: Wow, cool, but could please explain, from which verb the あらんこと part comes from, or what would be full form? (I can't find a translation of that part anywhere). Thanks!

Comment: Can you link the suspended sentences question?

Comment: フォースと共にあらんことを✙祈ります (the ellipsed verb phrase)

Answer (score 8):

It's just an ellipsis of the verb. It happens too with other particles, for example, you have "復興へ！" (towards reconstruction!) here and there in the Tohoku area.

I think that it is mostly used in an incentive context, to express "let's all…"

Comment: Would that apply in a case like this since を is between two nouns? 今も憶えているのあなた旅立つ日に見た夢**を**涙つたうあなたの頬 手を伸ばすと 闇の中消えた. Source: [link](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/KUON:_Memories_of_Waves_and_Light#Lyrics)

Comment: It's not the end of the sentence, but a swap of propositions. "The dream you saw, do you remember it?"