# "unfinished" sentences ending in particles like を, に and が

Tags: syntax

This is something I've always wondered about, but can't find any info about.

When native speakers come across a sentence that ends `...を。`, `...と。` or `...が！`*, how do their brains parse it? Is it just a case of being able to guess what word would follow based on their past exposure to collocations (words that go together with other words) and situations?

I found [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/does-the-particle-%E3%82%92-wo-have-a-special-use-when-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) to which the answers say it's verb ellipsis, which I get, but I'd like to know if there's any way of knowing exactly *which* verb – if there is indeed only one particular possibility — or whether the hidden verb belongs to a small group of verbs which are often omitted. For example, on TV an announcer said something like `次の日はすごい状態に！` I asked a Japanese friend what the verb would be and they immediately said `なった`. Is it likely they knew this from collocational knowledge, the same way an English speaker could finish the sentence `running around like a chicken with...`? And could `なった` have just as easily been a different verb it was a different situation, or is `状態に` *always* followed by `なる` if the verb is dropped?

*(not the が that means "but"; the other one. I have *no idea* how to interpret sentences that end with が – it's the most difficult one for me.)

More examples: [Here](http://livedoor.blogimg.jp/koyamaclinic/imgs/1/6/160a9169.jpg) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binb%C5%8D-gami_ga!)

Comment: Thanks but this is が with the meaning of "but" – I'm talking about when the sentence seems abruptly cut off. Still trying to find a good example!!

Comment: Do you have an example sentence that ends in `が` that is not the "but" one?

Comment: Yep, have a look at the title of this anime: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binb%C5%8D-gami_ga!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binb%C5%8D-gami_ga!)

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, there is usually some other context that was previously given, or is *completely* obvious even though it's omitted.  I refer to the former as a kind of "back reference" to whatever was said before.

> - A: めっちゃ難しい...　→　It's so hard/difficult
> - B: 何**が**？　→　What is?  (Since you would say Ｘが難しい)
>     
>   or
> - A: 明日母に送るわ。　→　I'll send it/this to my mother tomorrow. (Perhaps person B is out of the room and cannot see what A is talking about)
> - B: 何**を**？　→　What (will you send)?  (Since you say Ｘを送る)

or

> - ルールに書いてあります。キーパー以外の選手がボールに手を触れないように**と**　→　It's written in the rules.  "No player besides the goalie shall touch the ball with their hands".　→　Here, the と is the quotation marker, making the entire second sentence the "it" that's referenced in the first.

Some examples I often see of the implied-yet-omitted context are like

> - 良い一日**を**！　→　Have a good day　→　The "have" is omitted, but could/would be something like 過ごしてください

`ように` is **very** common to see at the end of a sentence to indicate "May something happen" / "Let it be that 〜"

> - 今年も祝福いっぱいの一年になりますよう**に**　→　(Said to someone on their birthday) "May this year (also) be one full of blessings"　→　The omission is clearly something like "I hope" (願っています) or "I pray" (祈っています)

---

For the book in your first example link, it's titled `夢に日付を！`.  It even says in English at the bottom "Date Your Dream", which, while grammatically correct, would be better translated as "Set a date for your dream (to come true)".  In this case, the "Set" part is what is omitted, so the full Japanese could be something like `夢に日付を入れる`.  I can't really explain how, but leaving off the `入れる` gives is more of an impact as a book title.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for such a detailed answer. The examples you gave of を and と are what I was getting at (and `ように` too, which I guess I didn't notice also fits this pattern!). The part about the `夢に日付を` book is right on the money though – it *could* be `入れる` as you say; is the idea that leaving out the verb makes it more "dynamic" or something? Leaving a bit of mystery, perhaps...? :)

Comment: "Always previous context" or "completely obvious" sorta covers most text you could ever read...
In my experience, unfinished sentences ending in particles appear quite often in official signs/slogans (in shops, on posters etc). Of course, the meaning can be inferred, but they are typically light on context.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that it tends to be signs/slogans that do it. Good point. I guess my Japanese still needs work though because sometimes it's not obvious at all to me :/

Comment: Typically you should fill in implicit "give!" when you see `X に Y を` pattern. _Flowers for Algernon_ is translated as 『アルジャーノンに花束を』.