# Why is there を in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

"夏を今もう一回"
What is を doing in this sentence, and what does it even mean?
It looks like "do one more time the present to the summer" which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: In what context did you see the phrase? I don't think it is completely natural. Anyway, think 今=now rather than present. It is like *summer once more*, where the grammatical role of *summer* is as vague as what verb is omitted in the phrase.

Comment: Related: ["unfinished" sentences ending in particles like を, に and が](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11624/78)

Comment: It was from a song lyric. If it helps, the next line is "君がいなくても笑って迎えるから"

Comment: Please read [my answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38220/5010). Carpenters' "Yesterday Once More" is often translated as "昨日**を**もう一度". I hope you can get the point of this を with this. A literal translation would be "(Give back to me) summer once more, now".

Answer (score 0):

A verb meaning 'to pass or spend [a period
of time]' has been omitted, e.g., 夏を今もう一回過ごす '[We] will spend summer now once again'. This sounds somewhat odd
out of context though. Perhaps something like 楽しむ is more appropriate, 夏を今もう一回楽しもう.

Comment: It was a lyric from a song. The next lyric is "君がいなくても笑って迎えるから"