# What is the meaning of "超か" in this news headline?

Tags: words, particle-か

I saw this in a news article saying that Toshiba had losses of \1T:

> 東芝、赤字１兆円超か

http://www.asahi.com/articles/DA3S12867082.html

What is the purpose of adding か at the end?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

超【ちょう】 is "over/above ～", the antonym for 未満.

> - 2m超のヘビ
> - 100kg超の体重

This か is a question marker. か after a noun/suru-verb is a typical "headlinese" expression meaning "there is a possibility that / suspicion of ～". It corresponds to a question mark in English headlines.

> - また賃金削減**か**
>     More Wage Cuts?
> - 英国、EU離脱**か**
>     UK to Exit EU? / UK Exits EU?
>     <sub>(referring to something that seems to have happened but is unconfirmed, or something that is likely to happen in the near future)</sub>

Similar expressions:

> - 英国、EU離脱**も**
>     UK May Exit EU
>     <sub>(referring to something not very likely but not impossible; ～もあり得る)</sub>
> - 英国、EU離脱**へ**
>     UK To Exit EU
>     <sub>(referring to something that is going to happen)</sub>