# Lack of の in 最強のポケモン誕生

Tags: particle-の

I was wondering why the sentence

> 最強のポケモン誕生

doesn't have a の between ポケモン and 誕生. Is there any reason to drop it? Sentences with 誕生日 normally include の (like 私の誕生日は。。。).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titles, news headlines, catchphrases and such are not constructed as ordinary sentences, and case particles are omitted aggressively. When we see 最強のポケモン誕生 in a catchphrase, we will assume が (not の) is omitted after ポケモン, and した after 誕生.

> 最強のポケモン誕生
> = 最強のポケモンが誕生した
> = (The) strongest Pokemon (was) born

Related:

- [what is the name of the abbreviated writing style used in newspapers?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14512/5010)
- [the omission of an implied "の" creates the appearance of a 四字熟語{よじじゅくご}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010)
- [What is the meaning of "超か" in this news headline?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45029/5010)

Comment: So 誕生 is actually a shortening of 誕生する? I was treating it like a noun (similar to 誕生日), hence the の. The sentence was actually the title of a Pokemon light novel chapter, so it all makes sense. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: @Jak Yes する/した is usually omitted in titles and such. Of course 誕生 can also be a noun ("birth") in a phrase like ポケモン誕生の秘密. By the way, [headlines in English are equally tricky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese).