# Understanding the に in 頭はクールに、ハートは苛烈に

Tags: particle-に

> 「もし十香が抱いたような感想を、皆が感じてくれていたなら御の字ね。みんなの戦意を高揚させるのも司令官の仕事だから。ーーでも、ただ熱狂するだけじゃあ駄目。頭はクール**に**、ハートは苛烈**に**、が理想ね」

頭はクールに、ハートは苛烈に sounds like a proverbial expression. Nevertheless, I’m curious about the grammatical function of the bold に. Could you please explain that?

Answer (score 2):

「頭はクールに、ハートは苛烈に」 is not an existing idiom nor a cliché, but it does sound like a catchy slogan because the corresponding verb is omitted. In this case, you may think something like しよう or 保とう is omitted after each に. (This に is technically a particle that turns na-adjectives into adverbs (i.e., "-ly"), but here it has a [resultative function](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55806/5010).)

Here are similar examples. Words in parentheses are omitted verbs.

- [日本を元気に](https://kyodonewsprwire.jp/release/202007152064) (しよう)
- [最高のヒーローに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/81005/5010) (なろう)
- [オリンピックを東京に](https://mainichi.jp/articles/20200330/k00/00m/050/192000c) (招致しよう)
- [手のひらを太陽に](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%B2%E3%82%89%E3%82%92%E5%A4%AA%E9%99%BD%E3%81%AB) (かざそう)

See Also:

- [Does the particle "を" (wo) have a special use when at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1209/5010)
- [Is it a right interpretation of the line of this Japanese song?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38210/5010)
- [can を comes at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76328/5010)