# おそれがある vs おそれあり

Tags: nuances, set-phrases

I recently found an example of おそれあり in a fictional headline

> 「ネットワークしはい計画が本格的にはじまったおそれあり」だって

Presumably this is "It says 'It may be that their plan for network domination has begun to go all out'"

The only example of おそれあり I was unable to find a dictionary definition, and could only find signs like "落石のおそれあり" through Google. Am I correct in that it is just a version of おそれがある? If so, what exactly is the nuance between these two phrases?

Comment: Note that even あり is dropped in real headline grammar. This would be something like "ネットワーク支配計画 本格始動[か](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45029/5010)".