# What does へ mean at the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, sentence, particle-へ

Just wondering what へ means in this context.

> 日本郵政「かんぽの宿」すべて売却へ

Seems like it might be implying that the "Kanpo no Yado" are going to sell off all its assets but I'm a little confused as to the specific meaning へ has here.

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of "超か" in this news headline?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45029/5010)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a specific usage to headlines in newspaper. Practically it means *it is going to happen*, which derives from the most basic sense of へ: direction.

The line in the question has が and を omitted: 日本郵政**が**「かんぽの宿」**を**すべて売却へ, which means *Japan Post will sell all of its 「かんぽの宿」 (hotel business).*

---

Exactly what particles are omitted varies, and to get the full meaning the omitted particles must be guessed.

- 東京オリンピック延期へ : *Tokyo Olympic games will be postponed.* （が is omitted, passive)
- Apple新型iPad発表へ : *Apple will reveal new iPad.* (が、を are omitted, active)
- 首相辞任へ : *Prime Minister will resign.* （が is omitted, active)

(The first can also be considered as を omitted and active: *They postpone...*)

---

Generally headlines ending in へ・も・か are used to avoid definitively stating something as a fact (especially も and か). (Cf. [新聞記事の「へもか」](http://fanblogs.jp/sagamimuneo/archive/103/0) )

Comment: English news(papers) tend to use infinitive there: [Apple **to** release four new iPhones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj-sxyz1A-A)