# What is the meaning of this 連用形 pattern?

Tags: grammar

> 政府、1日75万人の感染者想定し対策

Is it equivalent to 政府、一日七十五万人の感染者想定した対策?

What is the grammar behind this pattern?

Is 一日(に) abbreviated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes 連用形 can end a clause without て. The construction is called 連用中止(形). For example, see the following questions (you can search others on the site).

- [Is there a term for using conjugating verbs such that the sentence continues with another clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/45489)
- [Is the 「て」 missing from 「され」 in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33256/45489)

I assume it is a headline or something. Just like in English, headlines try to be succinct and often omit particles.

1日(に/あたり) are rather variants, as *X a day*/*X per day* in English.

A fuller version (not unique, of course) is

> 政府**は**1日**(に/あたり)**75万人の感染者**を**想定し**て**対策**を検討している**

---

Semantically 想定した対策 works perfectly. But omitting た in a noun modifying clause is generally not possible.

---

FYI Some other questions on headlines.

- [What is the meaning of "超か" in this news headline?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45029/45489)
- [What does へ mean at the end of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90600/45489)

Comment: Does that mean that 連用形 can be used without a comma? I often see a 語幹+、+動詞 pattern.

Comment: @Manab Yes it *can*, just because there are no strict rules for commas. As you see, it more often comes with a comma.