# Why is the particle へ used for direction here and does particle で here mean because of?

Tags: particle-で, particle-へ

> 大手電力4社「規制料金」値上げ申請へ 燃料費高騰で

Link to article:  https://news.tv-asahi.co.jp/news_economy/articles/000276919.html

Comment: Re へ, this should answer https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90600/45489

Answer (score -2):

Just like English, newspapers and online articles have special rules when writing titles.

As it stands, it's like writing

Four major electric power companies to file for "regulated rate" increase - due to high fuel prices

It is easier to read if [燃料費高騰で」is put at the start of the sentence.

燃料費高騰で 大手電力4社「規制料金」値上げ申請へ*

Which as a normal sentence would probably be something like:

燃料費高騰で大手電力4社の「規制料金」の値上げを申請について

*I'm not certain about the 「へ」

Comment: The question is specifically about the へ. Why post an answer if you are not certain about it?