# Meaning of か when not 'or' statement or question

Tags: particle-か

I was reading NHK and came across this headline

> 母親監禁し暴行か 同居家族4人が逮捕 草むらに6歳男児の遺体も

After putting it into Deepl it came out as

> Mother held captive and assaulted, 4 family members living together arrested, body of 6 year old boy in the grass.

As far as I've seen か is only used to make questions and for saying 'either .... or''', so what is か doing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "超か" in this news headline?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45029/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e8%b6%85%e3%81%8b-in-this-news-headline) It *is* a sort of question.

Comment: It seems like か is used the same in both, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that 「か」 in this case may be an indication of uncertainty about the situation, so maybe a similar feeling to what "purportedly", "allegedly", and so on would convey. Sometimes DeepL leaves out important context like that in favor of a more natural translation, I feel. I'm not a Japanese expert, so I hope you'll listen to a more advanced person on here who has experience answering these questions, if someone else answers!

This is my first answer on here, so sorry if I didn't do too good  I wanted to write a comment instead since I'm not quite sure of the answer, but it requires 50 reputation. Guess I'm trying to build it up somehow, but this might be an utter failure and I might be completely wrong, who knows!