# What does it mean when the kana を is at the end of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-を

I have seen a couple of instances of を being used at the end of sentence. From my limited knowledge, を is supposed to be used to indicate the direct object of a verb, but I have seen it following a verb, or just completely at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: Do these answer your question? [を at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76328/%e3%82%92-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) / [Does the particle "を" (wo) have a special use when at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/does-the-particle-%e3%82%92-wo-have-a-special-use-when-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the particle "を" (wo) have a special use when at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/does-the-particle-%e3%82%92-wo-have-a-special-use-when-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

It's a rhetorical style often used as an exhortative. We also see phrases ended with particles in other contexts and we can loosely compare it with when we use a prepositional phrase alone in English (although we don't have a particle for marking an object of a verb in English). Sentences such as 未来を！ 夢を！are difficult to translate. They imply action without specifying the action or the actor and invite a listener or reader to supply their own.