# What is the implied-verb represented by the sentence-ending を in the following context？

Tags: verbs, particle-を, reading-comprehension, sentence-final-particles

I am trying to understand the dialogue being spoken by the narrative character on the page below, specifically the fourth line of dialogue from the right in the picture.

> 「……さっきは何で、あんなことを？」

What is the implied-verb represented by the sentence-ending を in the above sentence, or is there a trick to figuring out what that verb might be, as mentioned [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/does-the-particle-%E3%82%92-wo-have-a-special-use-when-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41500/sentences-ending-in-%E3%82%92)？

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 何で、あんなことを?
>   Why did you ... such a ...?

If you understand the story correctly, the implied verb should be self-evident.  What happened to him a moment before (さっき)? What is her response to this question?

The omitted verb is する/やる ("to do").

> 何で、あんなことをした(んだ)?
>   Why did you do such a thing?

Judging from what's written in this page, あんなこと ("such a thing") refers to her (mock) attempt to kill the speaker with a knife.