# Grammatic relationships inside a sentence - parsing

Tags: grammar, particles, parsing

once again I need again your help:
I have this sentence and also its translation (same auther/text as [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60840/which-is-the-verb-belonging-to-the-particle-%e3%82%92)) :

> まだどこにも兆{きざ}していない死苦{しく}が、感覚{かんかく}を灼{や}けた鉄{てつ}のように真赤{まっか}に鍛{きた}えてくれるのを感{かん}じた。

I think I understand the first part well enough (まだどこにも兆{きざ}していない死苦{しく}が)

but I have problems parsing the second part because I am unsure which parts belong together and why it is 死苦 that heats the feelings.
Furthermore, I have trouble understanding the role of くれるの.

Anyway, I believe at least that 感覚{かんかく}を灼{や}けた鉄{てつ}のように真赤{まっか}に鍛{きた}えて belongs together.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

鍛える ("to train") is a transitive verb. Its subject is 死苦, and its object is 感覚. 灼けた鉄のように真っ赤に ("red-ly as heated iron") is an adverbial phrase that modifies 鍛える. This adverbial phrase is [結果構文](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55806/5010), therefore "I felt the deadly pain sharpen my senses so that they became red like heated iron" is the literal translation. It probably sounds fairly peculiar, but I think the original Japanese sentence is equally peculiar.