# sentence final を?

Tags: syntax, particle-を, collocations

I found numerous answers to the question...

[Does the particle "を" (wo) have a special use when at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1209/31150)

One comment says:

*It's like Japanese color-by-numbers: the outline is there, but you have to pick your own verb to finish the picture.*

My question is, to continue the analogy in the comment: among the crayons in the box, ***which*** verb (or verbs) does a native speaker choose to associate with the <を> in the following phrases?
Clearly, not all verbs will work equally well; there must be a short list of possibilities.

より甘【あま】く、より大【おお】きく、日本一【にっぽんいち】の味【あじ】を

*Sweeter, bigger, and the best taste in Japan.*

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASPBQ4GRFPB8PTLC00J.html?iref=comtop_Business_03

Comment: As one of the comments in the linked question says, a sentence like this is not a quiz or anything. Japanese people don't bother to try to imagine a particular verb each time they see a sentence like this. Instead, they just understand 日本一の味 is someone's desire or slogan, and keep reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just left to the reader's imagination, nothing more. In this case, the phrase in the linked article is followed by the description of how a chestnut (栗) breeder worked on improving his strains, and which lets me imagine verbs like 生み出す, 実現する, etc. But that's only after I read the rest of the passage.

If it was a catch copy on an advertisement of a sweet or something, I might imagine other verbs like 味わう instead.