# Why is konnichiwa spelt こんにちは?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, hiragana

Why is は used at the end of こんにちは? Is the last letter the [particle は](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/379/why-are-the-particles-%E3%81%AF-ha%E2%87%92wa-%E3%81%B8-he%E2%87%92e-and-%E3%82%92-wo%E2%87%92o-not-spelled-phonet), or is there a different explanation?

[Which is correct: こんばんわ or こんばんは?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/131/which-is-correct-%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%B0%E3%82%93%E3%82%8F-or-%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%B0%E3%82%93%E3%81%AF) mentions konnichiwa, but the question is interpreted more as "When should I use こんばんわ and when should I use こんばんは?"

Comment: “I guess gaikokujin tend to be more spoken-language-centric, whereas nihonjin tend to be more written-language-centric.”  Where did you get that idea?  Needless to say, Japanese children normally learn to speak Japanese before they can write.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [gogen-allguide](http://gogen-allguide.com/ko/konnitiwa.html), `こんにちは` originated from the `今日{こんにち}は` ("today") in `今日{こんにち}はご機嫌{きげん}いかがですか？` ("how are you today") and similar expressions.