# Is this furigana a typo?

Tags: furigana, kana-usage, obsolete-kana

I have a set of traditional poem cards. One of the poems has the line:

> 嵐の庭の
> 雪ならで

and furigana is given for the kanji. On the 庭 kanji, the furigana is には. My dictionaries give にわ instead. Is this a typo, or is this something to do with classical Japanese?

Comment: には is the traditional spelling pre-1945.  But the pronunciation is still にわ.

Comment: See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52189/40476 for more information on the history of the pronunciation of は.

Comment: Many dictionaries include classical spelling in the entry. https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BA%AD